# having the error " jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined " in flask and python

Tags: python, flask

i'm trying to add a contact form witch will store the data entered by the user in a csv file. How ever the site won't proceed to the page in which the contact for is and the pycharm is showing this error : jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
Here is the code regarding that form in app.py:

```
    class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
       name = StringField('Your Name: ', validators=[InputRequired(),length(2,10), 
              Regexp('^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9.]*$', 0,
              'Your name must start with a letter and can only include letters, numbers, dots')])
       email = EmailField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email()])
       message = TextAreaField('Message', validators=[InputRequired()], render_kw={'rows': 10})
       select = SelectField('In which category your order falls into ?', validators= 
                    [InputRequired()],
               choices=[('o1', 'Applique'), ('o2', 'Embroidery'), ('o3', 'PatchWork'), 
                          ('o4','Mixed'),('o5', 'Others')])
       submit = SubmitField('Submit')


    @app.route('/contact_form', methods=['Get','Post'])
    def handle_contact_form():
         form = ContactForm()
         if form.validate_on_submit():
              with open('data/contactInfo.csv', 'a') as f:
              writer = csv.writer(f)
              writer.writerow([form.name.data, form.email.data,form.message.data, form.select.data])
              flash('***sent successfully***')
              return redirect('/home')
         else:
             flash('oops!!!! Cant send message....')
             return render_template('/special', form=form)
```

and this is the code on the html file:

```
{% extends "BaseTemplate.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
{% block title %}SpecialOrder{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block header %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block contents %}
<div class="container">
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}{{ message }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
<form action="/contact_form" method="post" style=" padding: 60px">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}{{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name }}<br/>
    {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email }}<br/>
    {{ form.message.label }} {{ form.message }}<br/>
    {{ form.select.label }} {{ form.select }}<br/>
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

this the errors i recieve:

```
   127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2020 15:08:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
   [2020-04-14 15:08:26,089] ERROR in app: Exception on /special [GET]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
      packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
   response = self.full_dispatch_request()
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
         packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
           packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
         packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise raise value
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site 
      packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
      packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site - 
     packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\app.py", line 134, in 
         special
     return render_template("SpecialOrder.html")
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
         packages\flask\templating.py", line 140, in render_template ctx.app,
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
      packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
     rv = template.render(context)
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
      packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
      self.environment.handle_exception()
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
       packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
        reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\site- 
      packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
      raise value.with_traceback(tb)
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\templates\SpecialOrder.html", line 1, in top-level template code
     {% extends "BaseTemplate.html" %}
   File"C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\ 
          templates\BaseTemplate.html", line 154, in top-level template code
     {% block contents %}
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\ 
            templates\SpecialOrder.html", line 37, in block "contents"
     {{ form.csrf_token }}
   File "C:\Users\Nahid\PycharmProjects\Assignmet3\venv\lib\ site- 
          packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 471, in getattr
      return getattr(obj, attribute)
   jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
   127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2020 15:08:26] "GET /special HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: When `form.validate_on_submit()` is satisfied you are redirecting to the `/home` route and passing the form, however passing the form directly using `redirect` is not supported and is most likely not even what you are trying to do. If you really are trying to use the same form in the `/home` route, you will need to reinstantiate the form object there, just like you have done in this route with `form = ContactForm()`

Comment: What if I wanna redirect the user to the home page after he/she submitted the form? I tried to redirect the user to /home without passing the form, since its not needed there, but it is still giving me the same error

Comment: Is the Jinja2 error coming from your `/home` route or the `/special` route? Also you would not need to pass the form to simply send the user to another route after form submission, since you're not going to be processing that form in 2 locations, right

Comment: I think its coming from my /special route:

Comment: I also included all the lines with the error at the end to the contents of my question.

Answer (score 0):

This  seemes  no  the  right  way.
 I think  the  easy   way  is  to  put  in  the  else  part the represantation of  the  form. And  keep  the  if. About  the  error, you  can  make  an  if  inside the  else. Or  make  an  if  inside  the  jinja -html,meaning after  entering  data  ..something  went  wrong.
This  is  the  best  way in  my  opinion.

Comment: The  form  object  is  refered  in the  html before calling  it. Maybe  it  is  in  another  part  of  your  code...

Comment: Whenever possible, try to *show* rather than *tell*.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to adjust your route logic slightly. The error message you are seeing means that you are trying to load the HTML file without passing in the `form` object. There is a chance you are experiencing some type of circular reference issue where you redirect to another route and then redirect *back* to this one incorrectly, but without seeing the rest of your code it is impossible to know.

What I can tell you is that you will probably want your route to look more like this (edited for brevity)

```py
@app.route('/contact_form', methods=['GET','POST'])
def handle_contact_form():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # check some stuff
        if True:  # your stuff worked
            flash('Success')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        flash('Error')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('specialOrder.html', form=form)
```

When you call `form.validate_on_submit()` that is the same thing as saying `if request.method=='POST' and form.validate()`, which means that if either

- the request is not a POST request, or
- the form is not valid,

then the inner logic will *not* be executed. What I think is happening is that your route does not have a safe "fallback" for when this condition is failing, but because of some odd behavior (maybe with the Jinja2 template loader, which tries at all costs to find *something* to return) it is still trying to template the file as if you had just called `render_template('specialOrder.html')` with no form. Just thinking of all possibilities.

Comment: thanks. does the fact that I have 2 different forms in my code have any affect on this? Cause I also have a log in form

Comment: YES, that's a big thing to leave out! You're only sending the `ContactForm` to your HTML page, how is it supposed to get the other one?

Comment: the root and the class definition for both my log in form and contact form are in the same app.py, but they are used by different templates. the SpecialOrder.html only uses the ContactForm. Does that still affect the error?

Comment: The way your comment was worded it sounded like you had 2 forms in the same HTML page, which is totally fine--you just need to pass both of the forms in using your `render_template` function. Simply having multiple forms in the same app is not going to cause the error, since each function is a separate context. I'm not sure what more can be helped with what's available. I might suggest going through a tutorial and then trying to customize it for your use case, or just to learn the fundamentals so that you might be able to spot your error easier.